# How can I change the position of a specific toast per use case using ngx-toastr in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, toastr

I have been reading up on this on the actual site for ngx-toastr [ngx-toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr), and other posts on Stack Overflow, but cannot find a clear solution for my work case.

**I am trying to change the position of the `toastr` for specific use cases. Example; when it is an error, show the `toastr` on the top.**

I have a very vanilla setup.

In my `app.module.ts` I have the following:

```
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
```

In my imports of `app.module.ts` I have:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 3500,
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-center',
      preventDuplicates: true,
}),
```

In my components I declare the `toastr` in my `constructor`:

```
constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}
```

And I use the `toastr` as follows:

```
this.toastr.error('There was an error loading the Asset List!', 'Asset Register');
```

**As per my setup, all toast show in `'toast-bottom-center'`. How can I modify this call to show the toast on the top?**

```
this.toastr.error('There was an error loading the Asset List!', 'Asset Register');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a service for that.

Start by creating an enum

```
export enum ToasterPosition {
  topRight = 'toast-top-right',
  topLeft = 'toast-top-left',
  bottomRight = 'toast-bottom-right',
  bottomLeft= 'toast-bottom-left',
  // Other positions you would like
}
```

Now create your service

```
export class ToasterService {
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  public error(title: string, message: string, positionClass: ToasterPosition) {
    this.toastr.error(message, title, { positionClass });
  }
}
```

This way, you can't miss the positioning, since you have to provide an enum.

Answer (score 14):

The 3rd parameter of the *error* method is used to provide the position of the toastr message (among other things).

```
this.toastrService.error('There was an error loading the Asset List!', 'Asset Register');

this.toastrService.warning('Some warning message', 'some title', {
   positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in style.css

```css
.toast-top-center {
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Insert this in your toast function

```js
show(config: { type: string, title: string, subTitle?: string }): void {
  switch (config.type) {
        case 'Success':
          this._toastr.success(config.subTitle ? config.subTitle : '', config.title,{ positionClass: 'toast-top-center'});
          break;
        case 'Error':
          this._toastr.error(config.subTitle ? config.subTitle : '', config.title, { positionClass: 'toast-top-center'});
          break;
        case 'Warning':
          this._toastr.warning(config.subTitle ? config.subTitle : '', config.title, { positionClass: 'toast-top-center'});
          break;
        case 'Info':
          this._toastr.info(config.subTitle ? config.subTitle : '', config.title, { positionClass: 'toast-top-center'});
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
}
```